# The jQuery works only works on the first div when looping divs. I am still learning PHP and I can't figure out what's wrong

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I am a still learning PHP and I can't figure out what's wrong. The
jQuery is working on the first image only. I got the jQuery from
GitHub (I do not own it):

```
<script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js'>       
</script>
    <script src='jquery/jquery.zoom.js'></script>
    <script>

        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#ex1').zoom();


        });

    </script>


<?php
$budgetselect = 'SELECT * FROM `product_table` WHERE `item_category`="gaming"';
$budgetquery = mysql_query($budgetselect);
while ($data1 = mysql_fetch_array($budgetquery)) {
echo'
<form method="POST" action="process/addtocart.php">
<div id="product">
  <div id="prod_image">
  <span class="zoom" id="ex1">
  <img src="'.$data1['item_image'].'"width="65%" height="65%"/>
   </span>
  </div>
  <p><h2>'.html_entity_decode($data1['item_name']).'</h2></p>
  <div id="prodprice"><h2>PhP: '.$data1['item_price'].'</h2></div>
  <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="'.$data1['item_name'].'"/>
  <input type="hidden" name="item_price" value="'.$data1['item_price'].'"/>
  <input type="hidden" name="item_image" value="'.$data1['item_image'].'"/>
  <input type="hidden" name="item_quantity" value="1"/>

  ';

  if(isset($_SESSION['uid'])){
  echo'
  <div id="addtocart">
  <input type="image" src="img/mono-icons/addcart.png" width="32" height="32" alt="Add to cart" name="addcart"/>
  </form>
  </div>';
  }
  echo'<p>&nbsp;</p>
  <div id="description">

    <p>'.html_entity_decode($data1['item_description']).'</p>
  </div>
</div>

';
}
?>`
```

`

Comment: That jQuery will only run once when the page loads and it will only work on the element with the ID of #ex1. Elements on a page should have unique ID's so the behaviour you describe would be expected. I'd suggest adding a class to each of the elements you want to be affected by the jQuery and running on the class instead.

Comment: As @BillyMoat said, remove the fixed id (concat with a counter for example) and use the class you already has "zoom" to apply the jquery. [$('.zoom').zoom();]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Script
    Replace this

```
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.ex1').zoom();


        });

</script>
```

in place of this

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#ex1').zoom();


    });

</script>
```

HTML

Replace this

```
<span class="zoom ex1">
```

in place of

```
<span class="zoom" id="ex1">
```

Comment: You are awesome! I didnt figure that out. Thank you!